Saved notebooks on new Mathematica install do not reopen
I recently installed Mathematica on a new machine. The new machine is running version 12, and I believe the old machine was running version 10 (though I don't have it in front of me). I have been working on some notebooks that I had started on the previous machine, and saving them periodically. It now turns out that none of the saved notebooks on the new machine can be reopened after closing the file. Mathematica says they are corrupt (the exact error message is: "There was a syntax error on line 509 of the cell expression. The error was: Cell[BoxDat"), and the notebook recovery tool just deletes every single line from the notebook.
What could possibly be the reason for this, and is there anything I can do to get my work back? I can open the versions of the notebooks from before migrating to the new machine, but not any of the versions saved since migrating.
